# How to get back a card in Google now which was removely accidentaly?

Tags: google-now, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have recently installed Google Now app in my Note 3 and I found its working and helping me in my daily work.

By any unknown command I swipe the informatiom on the card it appears for me. Now when I want it back it will never turn on. Any idea on how to get the cards back or how to add a new card manually for any information we need in the nearly future?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Could you [edit] your question and explain a bit further? Are you trying to get back cards you've dismissed?

Comment: I mean the cards which appears in google now through my daily search results . I need tht to edit or atleast I can add a card for any update I require for any perticular subject. E.g I was searching for bb q20 for some page and it automatically showed me the release date the next day. Which was quite good but I swipe to delete by mistake which I dont know how to get it back .

Comment: @user53714 Were you able to configure that in Google Now. It availble in the Google Now settings. You ca now manually configure the card that you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

on the bottom of google now there are 3 icons. Click the magic wand (middle one) and select others. There find the topic and tell Gnow that you are still interested.

New cards will be added automatically once you search for them with google now. Once a new cad appears tap the three dots in the upper right of the card and than yes when prompted if interested.

Comment: I cant see any middle button but I can see the magic wand on my right which is only 2 icons in total. When I click it there is no others option in it the last . The only option in it is everything else where there is no such option to mark or redo the correction

Answer (score 0):

*Google Now Cards appears when needed..
For example:
You went to shopping then Google track your location and it will show a  Google now CARD on your Notification Screen as well on Google now Page saying that " You are _ Km from your home, and shows you path to get your home back.
Etc.. There are many others like show you a card of whether if you went to some another state or country.. Etc. Etc..

It will show when needed and you manually can't get cards.

Play with Settings in Google now to know more.